# Using bit integer programming on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I am working on a bit integer programming model and my constraints is such that the number of solutions to the optimization problem can be greater than 1.
However bintprog function in MATLAB outputs one of the feasible solution instead of all.

Example of this observation

```
f = [-9; -5; -6; -4]; 
A = [6 3 5 2; 0 0 1 1; -1 0 1 0; 0 -1 0 1];
b = [9; 1; 0; 0];
x = bintprog(f,A,b)
```

Output

```
[1 1 0 0]
```

If I change parameter **f** such that f = [0; 0; 0; 0], then **output** = [0 0 0 0].
But we know that along with this output, above output also satisfy these set of constraints. Therefore, **Bintprog** outputs only one feasible solution.

Can you please suggest a way in which I can get all the feasible solutions (will be finite in my case) byy using bit integer programming in MATLAB.
Many thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You can try using `feassol.` It is meant for continuous variables, but you might be able to make it work for your `Bintprog`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, is this what you need -

Code -

```
f = [-9; -5; -6; -4]; 
A = [6 3 5 2; 0 0 1 1; -1 0 1 0; 0 -1 0 1];
b = [9; 1; 0; 0];
x = bintprog(f,A,b)'

new_f = [0;0;0;0];
f = [f;new_f]';
A = repmat(A,[1 2]);
x = bintprog(f,A,b)'
```

Output -

```
x =
     1     1     0     0
x =
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Let us know!

Comment: f function will remain same. I meant to say that the feasible solution will be more than one, so how to output all of those with the same optimization problem and constraints

Answer (score 0):

bintprog() attempts to find an optimal, feasible solution using the branch and bound algorithm. This algorithm is deterministic. Therefore given an objective function and set of equality/inequality constraints, it should produce the same output no matter how many times it is run. Therefore, the answer to your question is no.